# Display Chinese Text on Web Page

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, cjk

This has been asked before, but the other poster's concern had more to do with the original encoding of the document.

I have a MySQL database containing some Chinese text. The Collation I am using for those fields is `utf8_unicode_ci`. Using phpMyAdmin and browsing the database, the Chinese text appears as it should. When I try to display this text on a webpage however, I get ????? in it's place. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    ?>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // Code opening database and retrieving fields and such...
```

Is there something I am missing? I've also tried moving the PHP `header()` call to above the `<html>` tag but that doesn't work either.

**EDIT:** Here is the database code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "pass") or die('Sorry, could not connect to database server');
mysql_select_db("database_name", $con) or die('Sorry, could not connect to database');
$query = "SELECT id,field1,field2 FROM table1 ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Sorry, could not get recipes at this time ');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $var1= $row['field1'];
            $var2= $row['field2'];
            echo"ID:$id The contents are $var1 and $var2.<br><br>\n";
 }
```

**UPDATE:** So I've addressed the issue with reading in the stored Chinese characters as UTF-8 using the line `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);`, but I am finding that when I want to add to this database, the Chinese text shows up as ????? again. For instance, if I am saving a string of Chinese characters as a variable

```
$chinese = "炒猪肉与蔬菜";
echo "$chinese<br>";
```

This shows ????? again. Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the database code, that's probably where the problem is

Comment: `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

Comment: Please read [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: Reading the link provided by deceze, the fix was to add the line `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);` after `mysql_select_db()`. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin: yep, that's typically the case; please consider adding this as an answer and marking it correct. BTW if your echo code above is real code and not just for demonstration purposes, you'll need `htmlspecialchars` to avoid HTML-injection->XSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great resource: [Handling Unicode Front to Back in a Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

The fix for the initial question was to add the line `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);` after the line `mysql_select_db();`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the actual file encoding is wrong. Try opening the output file in say "Notepad++" and see what encoding it detects in bottom right corner. If it's not utf-8 convert it to utf-8 in the same "Notepad++".

Answer (score 0):

Your webpage is OK, so the problem may be the SQL charset. You already set the charset correctly. If you still see question marks when retrieving the data, this is most likely because you saved it in the wrong way. Whenever you want to save Unicode to database, use **N** before the strings:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES N'炒猪肉与蔬菜'
```

Comment: Interesting. I actually fixed the problem by encoding the .php file as UTF-8 (it was ANSI previously). This was the final fix i needed.